# PHP read the URL for search (Apache)

Tags: php, apache, url, search

I need in the

```
url: domain.com/search/hola
```

to ignore this `hola` (so go to `/search/index.php`) but have this `hola` in a php variable.

For example i type `domain.com/search/google` in my browser, then go to `domain.com/search/index.php` with the code:

```
$search = $_GET['url']; //(obviously, this doesn't works)<br>
print_r($url);
```

Something like that: http://example.com/ put what you put go to the same site.

Comment: Take a look at `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Comment: Where is your code ?!

Comment: Is the URL already redirected to your index.php? If not, a `RewriteRule` in a .htaccess file can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a RewriteRule.

Install the module mod_rewrite into your Apache. Depending on your server and OS, instructions may differ, but most of the time it's already installed.

Check that `AllowOverride All` is specified in your Apache's site configuration to allow .htaccess files.

Create a .htaccess file in the root folder of your webserver.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^/search/(.*)    /search/index.php?param=$1    [L,QSA]
```

If you do any changes in your apache configuration or install a new module, you  will have to restart the apache service. Changes in a .htaccess file do not require a restart.

- HowTo http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Error: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^/search/(*.)'

Comment: Repared: RewriteRule    ^/search/(.*)    /search/index.php?param=$1    [L,QSA]